# How to set state for variable function

Tags: reactjs

I have a component (Father.js) that have these 2 variables that use state:

```
const [streetAddress1, setstreetAddress1] = useState();
const [streetAddress2, setstreetAddress2] = useState();
```

And also a function declared this way:

```
const setValues = (value, name) => {
    if(name === 'streetAddress1'){
        setStreetAddress1(value);
    }
    else if(name === 'streetAddress2'){
        setStreetAddress2(value);
    }
}
```

And then I have a child component which is called this way:

```
<Child objectNr="1" setValues={setValues} />
<Child objectNr="2" setValues={setValues} />
```

The Child components have input fields that on blur will set the address. I coded it this way:

```
<input
    type="text"
    onBlur={ (e) => setValues(e.target.value, `streetAddress${objectNr}`)} />
```

This works. However, having a lot of similar variables that uses state, I wonder if it is possible in the function setValue to just run the set-method depending on the incoming string. So as the first child is sending th string "streetAddress1" I would like the function setValue to just run the set-method for that variable, without needing to run a lot of if-statements. is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want to use an object or array in state instead:

```
const [streetAddresses, setStreetAddresses] = useState({});
```

```
<Child objectNr="2" setStreetAddresses={setStreetAddresses} />
```

```
onBlur={
  (e) => {
    setStreetAddresses(addresses => ({
      ...addresses,
      [objectNr]: e.target.value
    }));
  }
```

Or you could put the index and/or state combination logic into the parent instead, whatever is cleaner for your setup:

```
// in father.js:
const makeSetAddress = objectNr => e => {
  setStreetAddresses({
    ...streetAddresses,
    [objectNr]: e.target.value
  });
};
// and pass it down:
<Child objectNr="2" setAddress={makeSetAddress(2)} />
// might be able to omit objectNr above
// if it isn't being used anywhere else but the state setter
```

```
onBlur={setAddress}
```